# How to create a square shaped div inside an arbitrary circle?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am using Javascript to create an SVG element that contains a circle with a radius and a stroke thickness. The size and thickness may vary. I'm trying to create a square shaped div that would fit inside this SVG circle, so that I may add content inside the circle.

You can imagine the content to be anything from a text containing information about the circle, an anchor, or a button.

The rectangle must fit in the circle in so that all content is wrapped, and if there is no space, the content will be removed.

[Here is the raw Sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsIoy.png)

```html
    <!-- A minified example of what the Javascript outputs -->
    <svg viewBox="0 0 80 80" width="80" height="80">
        <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="35"></circle>
    </svg>
```

My main question is if it's possible to add this solely to the SVG element, and using something like the styling: `left: 10%; top: 10%; width:50%; height: 50%`, or if this would require more advanced CSS or Javascript trickery.

It's important to also mention that my circle has a radius of `(svgWidth / 2) * 0.875` that is set from within the Javascript code.

Comment: any reason for using SVG? it's more simple to consider pure CSS for the circle and building it from the square and going up

Comment: The side of the square would have to be exactly `sqrt(2) * radius` I think.  But there's no way to obtain that value with SVG only. Either pre-compute the size of the square (in JS maybe? or even server-side) if it's an option OR use CSS and `calc`.

Comment: I've got the radius present in my Javascript file! So that won't be an issue!

Comment: I'm using SVG because I could animate it.

Comment: can you use `transform: translate();` Css property for this?

Comment: Is there a difference between `transform: translate();` and giving the div a `top` and `left` value?

Comment: So updating the div with a `left` and `top` of `(sqrt(2) * radius)` would resolve the issue. How about the `width` and `height`, would that just be `radius - left` and `radius - top`?

Comment: Then you need to compute the width/height of the square with `sqrt(2) * radius` and use the result when generating the SVG. You probably want a `<rect width="x" ...`.

Comment: Okay, so I'm mixing up the offset with the size. `sqrt(2) * radius` would tell me the size, not the offset.

Comment: If you know the rectangle size (square root of [circle radius squared / 2] = 49.49. the offsets would be SVG width - 49.49 = 15.51 - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/qvRRxB

Comment: Thanks Paulie! Happened to have also created the solution at the same time as you. If you could add it as the solution I'll mark yours and remove mine.

Comment: No need...My JS is terrible so I'm happy to leave yours there.

Comment: Alright, thank you everyone for your help. Enjoy your days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for. You can resize the SVG and see everything resizes accordingly.

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container svg {
  fill: #dedede;
  stroke: #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.container svg g > .text-holder {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.container svg g > .text-holder > p {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.container svg g > circle {
  cx: 50%;
  cy: 50%;
  r: 50%;
}

.container svg g > rect {
  stroke: #f00;
  x: 15%;
  y: 15%;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 80 80">
    <g>
        <circle></circle>
        <rect></rect>
        <foreignObject class="text-holder" x="15%" y="15%" width="70%" height="70%">
          <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size: 12px;">Text goes here</p>
        </foreignObject>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay, thanks to @Sergiu I found the right mathematical equation to solve it, this was the primary issue. The code below is taken out of my Javascript code and shows how I create a `rect` that fits exactly like the square my image.

```
        var squareSize = Math.sqrt(2) * radius - circleStrokeThickness;
        var squareCenter = (svgWidth - squareSize) / 2;

        this.rectangleContent = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect');
        this.rectangleContent.setAttribute('x', squareCenter);
        this.rectangleContent.setAttribute('y', squareCenter);
        this.rectangleContent.setAttribute('width', squareSize);
        this.rectangleContent.setAttribute('height', squareSize);
        this.rectangleContent = $(this.rectangleContent).appendTo(this.svg);
```

This is not a div but it already answers all of the questions I had about the placement of the div.

[image: Result]